# tikzpicture won't render 'usable' PS code

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, compiling, postscript

I use tikz (and tikzpicture) a fair bit, but files that used to compile fine before the latest slew of updates to pgf, and pstricks, no longer seem to do so (at least, on my MikTeX installation). The MWE (below) seems to compile correctly, but the DVI can't be rendered using yap, and dvi -> ps -> pdf fails (the dvi -> ps seems to be ok -- to the extent it isn't throwing errors), but ps2pdf fails miserably, with the following errors:

```
 Error: /undefined in XC@.
 Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   - 
-nostringval--   --nostringval--
Execution stack:
%interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   -- 
nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   -- 
nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   2045   1   3   %oparray_pop   
2044   1   3   %oparray_pop   2025   1   3   %oparray_pop   1884   1   3   
%oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval- 
-   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
  --dict:979/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:87/200(L)--   -- 
  dict:182/300(L)--   --dict:58/200(L)--
  Current allocation mode is local
  Current file position is 99615
  GPL Ghostscript 9.26: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{decorations,shapes,arrows,matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.175cm,y=0.175cm,scale=1]

% set up maximum and minimum x- and y-coordinates
\def\xmin{0}
\def\xmax{23.5}
\def\ymin{0}
\def\ymax{23.5}

% draw and label axes
   \draw[->,thick] (\xmin,0) -- (\xmax,0) node[below=8pt,near end] 
{\small{abundance ($N$)}};
  \draw[->,thick] (0,\ymin) -- (0,\ymax) node[above=12pt,near 
 start,rotate=90] { \small{birth rate ($b$)}};

% draw vertical reference line at K/2=50
  \draw[color=black, thick,  smooth] (0,20) -- (20,0) 
node[below=6pt,midway,rotate=-45] {\small{slope~$=a$}};

% draw circle around point where function intersects x-axis
\draw [red] (0,20)  ellipse (0.2cm and 0.2cm) node[right=3pt,black] {$b_0$};

 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Confirmed that its something about the new pgf and/or PSTricks (or interaction of the two). If I roll back to versions of both before the big January updates, MWE compiles and renders perfectly.

Comment: `dvipdf` throws also errors when running it on the generated dvi. (This may indicate that the `ps` is not the problem.) `pstricks` does not seem to be involved here.

Comment: Rather `xcolor`-related (I guess).

Comment: So in theory, then, if xcolor is the culprit, turing off all the colors in the MWE should 'solve the problem', correct? So, first I turned off all the colors in MWE. Then, I re-applied all the updates, including PSTricks, but left the pgf out of the loop. Compiled fine. Then, applied the pgf update. Compiled fine. Closing the loop, put the colors 'back into the MWE'. Problem re-occurs. So, problem is a nasty interaction of xcolor (presumably) and pgf?

Comment: @JohnnyCanuck: `xcolor` is loaded by default and _all_ documents use at least _one_  color: black or in `xcolor` notation `XC@.`

Answer (score 4):

the `dvips` driver of `pgf/tikz` is buggy!

```
[...]
\begin{center}
\special{ps: /XC@. {0 setgray } def }
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.175cm,y=0.175cm,scale=1]
[...]
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{prologue}{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
[...]
```

Comment: OK -- but for us mere mortals, now what? ;-) Meaning, if this is a pug (in your estimation) should I file it as such with the pgf maintainers, or something else?

Comment: sure! `tikz` should pass the option `prologue` to `xcolor` if it detects that a `dvi` output will be created.

Comment: OK -- I'll file a bug. In the meantime, am I correct in interpreting your post that the 'workaround' solution in the interim is to use either \special or \PassOptions?

Comment: yes and `\PassOptionsToPackage` should be preferred, if you use several colors.

Comment: OK -- I initially tried inserting \special{ps: /XC@. {0 setgray } def } before every tikzpicture, but when I save the file, it seems to disappear if the file is \included (I use \includefrom, actually) (say, the file is an individual chapter). Haven't tried PassOptionsToPackage, but...is there a  reason the \special approach doesn't 'stick' in the file if the file is \included (in some fashion)?

Comment: Actually, solved the problem. But turns out that it isn't quite as simple as the single suggestion you made. I just tried compiling a full document, and although the tikzpicture I used in the MWE now works, others don't. I'll open another thread with the 'collection' of issues that new pgf seems to have caused.

Comment: put `\special` _ before_ the `center` environment if it should be global

Comment: Danke -- I just posted a bug report with the pgf/tikz folks.

Comment: @Herbert Can you send me a patch for the dvips driver?

Comment: @HenriMenke: send it to your gmail account

Comment: @Herbert Thank you! [Merge is pending](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/git/merge-requests/21/) so the fix will be in the next release, which will hopefully be in TL pretest.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in PGF. Unfortunately, it has been introduced right before the release of the last stable -- apparently in the middle of our final tests such that it passed unnoticed.

Please do not use the suggested workaround (with the prologue option) since it breaks all colors with spaces in their name. This includes pgfplots with its `mapped color`.

We are sorry for it and will release a hotfix release soon.

References: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/503/