# TikZ node text color not working with latest MiKTeX release

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, ghostscript, miktex-update

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table}{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\par Text before

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[text=blue] {test};  %% This line produces the error
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\par Text after

\end{document}
```

Before the new year's MiKTeX update, I was able to write :

```
\node[blue] {test};
```

and the text within the node would be rendered blue. Since the update, however, this syntax creates a GhostScript (ps2pdf) `Error: /undefined in XC@.`.

For some reason, at certain places in my documents, I now have to explicitly write `\draw[draw=red]` instead of `\draw[red]` or I get a similar error.

I have therefore tried using `\node[text=blue]`, but to no avail. I know I could simply use `\textcolor{blue}{...}` inside the node to achieve the same effect, but my question is as follows: **is this currently a bug in TiKz or MiKTeX, or is it a new change in syntax/features**? (or alternatively, is my MiKTeX installation just fubar-ed...)

As with similar TikZ/PGF/PSTricks issues since the MiKTeX update, the .ps file seems to be properly generated (no actual errors during compilation), but the PDF conversion that ensues fails miserably, thus not producing a viable output document.

Comment: You need to pass the prologue option to xcolor. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470082/2388.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: agreed, possible duplicate. But none of these posts actually have a definitive answer. I thought the most recent update was supposed to have fixed these issues.

Adding the "prologue" option to xcolor does solve the problem in the MWE, but not in my vastly more complicated documents. It just switches the GhostScript `Error: /undefined in XC@.` to this new one:

    `Error: /undefined in color
    Operand stack:
       XC@mapped`

Comment: The comment of Henri says that the next pgf version will solve the problem but this isn't on ctan yet. For your new problem ask a new question with a suitable example.