# ps2pdf error with \arrow in chemfig package

Tags: chemfig, ps2pdf

The conversion of `dvi` to `pdf` fails when using the `\arrow` command. For instance, the file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\schemestart
A\arrow B
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

returns:

```
Error: /undefined in XC@. Operand stack: --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- Execution stack: %interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostring

val-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push 2045 1 3 %oparray_pop 2044 1 3 %oparray_pop 2025 1 3 %oparray_pop 1884 1 3 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- %errorexec_pop .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- Dictionary stack: --dict:961/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:1/20(G)-- --dict:88/200(L)-- --dict:178/300(L)-- --dict:58/200(L)-- Current allocation mode is local Current file position is 33303 GPL Ghostscript 9.26: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Thank you for helping !

Comment: I have tried with Papeeria that it use TeXlive 2015 and your code works correctly. What OS you use and what is your LaTeX distribuition? Maybe your distribution could be obsolete.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my distribution is not obsolete.

Comment: I can confirm the problem with with up-to-date texlive2018

Comment: @Sebastiano If something is obsolete here, then it's texlive 2015. I also bet that papeeria does not use the same compilation route as the OP, hence it will never reproduce the problem.

Comment: The compilation runs well with TeX Live 2017. With TL 2018 `chemfig` is version 1.33; was 1.2e with TL 2017. The differences are huge.

Comment: @GézàLaTeX Excuse me for my comment. I thought that the problem was the distribution.

Comment: `chemfig` depends on `PGF`/`TikZ`. `PGF` v3.1 has a bug in its `dvips` driver which will be fixed in the next release, acc. to this topic: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470077

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, the dvi file produced with TL2018 contains `'color push  XC@.'`, which is the source of the problem. I'm not sure what's the cause, but if you add

```
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
```

to force a color model and avoid `cmyk`, the problem vanishes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\schemestart
A\arrow B
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Forcing `cmyk` works as well.

Comment: It is an issue with the recent PGF update and its `dvips` driver.

Comment: @AlexG I suspected so.