# Incompatibility between pgfplots and xcolor since last MiKTeX update

Tags: pgfplots, color, miktex, ghostscript

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{prologue,usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table}{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{Blue!55!Green}{Text here}

\end{document}
```

Since the new year's MiKTeX update, the `xcolor` package must be loaded along with the `prologue` option in order to counteract interaction bugs with PSTricks, TiKZ, etc. (as noted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470077/tikzpicture-wont-render-usable-ps-code)).

However, if `xcolor`+`prologue` is loaded BEFORE `pgfplots`, it generates the following GhostScript error:
`Error: /undefined in color, Operand Stack: XC@mapped`.

If `xcolor`+`prologue` is loaded AFTER `pgfplots`, the following error arises during compilation (LaTeX=>PS=>PDF):
`! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color 'Blue'.`

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Just updated MiKTeX + Refresh FNDB + Rebuild Fonts after seeing your comment. Still get the same errors on my side.

Comment: Yes, Admin + User, both updated, both refreshed. This is explicitely compiled through the (LaTeX=>PS=>PDF) build profile on a MiKTeX installation. Not sure which engine is used (pdfLaTeX?), but I don't know XeLaTeX. The GhostScript error appears when attempting to convert from PS to PDF. As stated in similar posts, the PS is generated properly, but the conversion process fails.

Trying to uninstall, clean and fresh reinstall to see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Same results with clean install and all updates applied. The MWE does compile through XeLaTeX, but I explicitely need it to compile through LaTeX=>PS=>PDF (latex+GhostScript).

Answer (score 8):

I can reproduce the problem on texlive. pgfplots defines a color with a space in its name (`mapped color`). When using the (needed) prologue option this is passed to ghostscript (through the generated xcp file):

```
 /XC@mapped color{0 0 0}XCrgb
```

and ghostscript doesn't like this at all.

A similar error can be triggered with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[prologue]{xcolor}

\definecolor{some color}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\begin{document}
blub

\end{document}
```

This is imho a bug in pgfplots. It should change the color name.

Comment: Is there anything we can do about it? Until this is resolved, unfortunately, none of my documents will compile...

Comment: Well in your example I can avoid the problem by escaping the space, but as soon as the color is *used*  it explodes again, so you would sit on a bomb ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, before I contact Christian because of this issue and ask him to fix this: Where is the difference to the time before this years TikZ update? Was that working before that or is this a bug that exists quite a long time and just showed up now? Does Herbert's fix mentioned in [this comment](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/git/merge-requests/21/) fix this issue here, too?

Comment: @StefanPinnow You should ask Herbert about the dvips details. I don't know much about the low-level postscript. But I do know that spaces in internal (color) names is a *very* bad idea - you always have to think about the need to escape or remove or protect such spaces. And Herberts fix imho does not solve this issue, it made it appear: with the prologue option the color names are copied into the postscript, and so the space harms.

Comment: @StefanPinnow, I was compiling my documents last fall (let's say november to be sure) with updated LaTeX packages, so the issue is new. The code to which you link only seems to FORCE the prologue option in pgfcore.sty, which is already loaded in the MWE above.

Comment: Thank you to both of you for the clarification. I guess this is enough information to contact Christian ;)

Comment: The prologue option was introduced in https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/git/ci/4b87b9b54839d71871c0cadd7bd127144f9a7871/.  It's required to fix https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/503/.

Comment: @StefanPinnow, do you have an update on the situation? Did Christian mention he would be working on a fix?
@UlrikeFischer, in which file did you find the `\XC@mapped color{0 0 0}XCrgb` code?

Comment: No, nothing yet, but you can have an eye on https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/217/ to not miss any news ;)

Comment: @feculededentier the code is as mentioned in my answer in the generated `xcp` file. The color itself is defined and used in various files of pgfplots.

Comment: Confirmed: replacing `mapped color` by `mappedcolor` (space removed) everywhere in `pgfplots.code.tex`, `pgfplotsmeshplothandler.code.tex` and `pgfplotsplothandlers.code.tex` fixes the issue. Documents now compile normally.

Comment: @feculededentier I can concur that that resolves the issue (which still seems to happen even with Texlive 2019 and updating to the newest PGF despite the fact that the fix was supposed to be included with that).

Comment: @JAB at least it allows us to compile for now. I had forgotten `util/pgfplotscolormap.code.tex` in the list of files where the change needed to be made.

Comment: @JAB the bug is not in pgf but in pgfplots. But pgf has been fixed and no longer needs the `prologue` option, so as a work-around you can simply remove `prologue` (unless you need for some reason named colors in the postscript).

Comment: @feculededentier ^^^^

Comment: @UlrikeFischer my apologies for getting the packages mixed up, and thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

This question is actually "just" a result of the proposed solution of [tikzpicture won't render 'usable' PS code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470077/tikzpicture-wont-render-usable-ps-code) .

The issue is invalid and the solution for the linked question needs to be changed. I will update it as soon as the solution is ready.

Comment: Closed issue as duplicate.